# Yii bootstrap inside module

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions, yii-modules

I'm trying to include yii bootstrap from module. I want to keep it in /modules/myModule/extensions/bootstrap and all config params outside main config. Is it possible?

Currently in myModule init i do

```
$this->setImport(array(
'myModule.models.*',
'myModule.components.*',
'myModule.extensions.yiistrap.helpers.TbHtml',
'myModule.extensions.bootstrap.components.*',
'myModule.extensions.bootstrap.widgets.*'
));


if (!Yii::app()->hasComponent('bootstrap')) {
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__) . '/extensions/bootstrap');
Yii::createComponent('bootstrap.components.Bootstrap')->init();
Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();
}
}
```

and it works for some widgets, but for most I get error

```
Property "CWebApplication.bootstrap" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set application bootstrap component, this should work:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__) . '/extensions/bootstrap');
$bootstrap = Yii::createComponent('bootstrap.components.Bootstrap');
$bootstrap->init();
Yii::app()->bootstrap = $bootstrap;
$bootstrap->register();
```

To pass config into bootstrap:

```
$config = array(
    'class' => 'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
    'option1' => ...
);
$bootstrap = Yii::createComponent($config);
```